# How do I change where databases are created in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

By default, all new databases are created on `C:\`. I need them to be created on `E:\`. My first instinct was to move the database files for the model database, but SSMS is not giving me the option to detach it.

So, my question is, is there a way to set up the server so that all of the new databases are created on `E:\` by default?

Comment: I've used this: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=82885 -- it seems to work for DBs created through SSMS, but I had issues with a vendor product which created its own DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SSMS, right click on the server and choose "Properties". On the "Database Settings" page of the Server Properties window, specify your new locations for data and log files.

[image]

You could also do this with T-SQL by writing directly to the registry:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', REG_SZ, N'E:\YourData'
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultLog', REG_SZ, N'E:\YourLogs'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide here for SQL Server 2000 og 2005, my guess it's probably the same for SQLServer 2008:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071

Go down to the "Moving the model database" section.

I hope this helps.